# Remove a Cydia tweak that breaks iOS

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, ios, cydia

I've hidden Cydia and Poof! With the Poof! Cydia tweak. Now I cannot open either one of both of them.

Is there any way to undo this?
I've tried respringing and rebooting but that does not place them back.

Comment: I've edited the question to be less localized as the answer (an excellent one) applies to any tweak and can help others with problems similar to yours.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*If you have version 0.9.3997 or greater of [MobileSubstrate](http://cydia.saurik.com/info/mobilesubstrate/)…*

1. Turn off your phone.
2. Turn it back on, then while the Apple logo is shown, hold the Volume Up button.

This enables Safe Mode, disabling all MobileSubstrate tweaks temporarily, allowing you to uninstall the tweak that's causing problems. If you still want the tweak, you can reinstall it, deleting the preference file for the tweak in question to reset it.

To exit Safe Mode, you can respring/reboot your device, or press Exit Safe Mode in the status bar, then press Restart.

If you have a tethered jailbreak, you'll need to hold volume up whilst pressing 'Just Boot' and continue holding even after the Apple logo since Substrate won't load immediately.

Answer (score -1):

I think it will be fine if you restore your iPhone again and [Cydia download](http://cydia-download.com/) again on your iPhone

Comment: This question was asked in **2013**. And at the current moment, you cannot restore your iOS device to a jailbreakable version.